# Add the current Date.Now to a TimeSpan?

Tags: c#, datetime

This is similar to this link: ["Add the current time to a DateTime?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3582217/440310) but mine is quite different.

I would like to know how to add your timespan (example: 10:00AM) to your Date.Now (ex. 7/3/2013)? I've tried the `DateTime.Now.Add(timeSpan)` but it does not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to look at the returned value...

Comment: How does it 'not work'? 10:00AM is not a timespan, but `DateTime.Add` takes a timespan parameter, so if you have one it should work. Be aware that a new `DateTime` is returned, it does not modify the value of `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: @Lee: How it does not work? It's because instead of getting 7/3/2013 10:00am, I get 7/4/2013 4:00am. I don't want to use string manipulation because that will be "stupid coding".

Comment: @Musikero31 The `DateTime.Now` already has a time-of-day component (which is not midnight). Start from `DateTime.Today` if you want today's date without (with zero) time-of-day component!

Answer (score 3):

DateTime is immutable so your existing variable won't change.

```
var myDateTime = DateTime.Now.Add(timeSpan);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `+` operator:

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromHours(10);
DateTime result = DateTime.Now + ts;
```

However, `DateTime.Add` should work also. I assume that your "TimeSpan" is a string instead.

Since your timespan contains the AM/PM designator you can parse it to `DateTime` instead and add the `TimeOfDay`-TimeSpan to `DateTime.Now`:

```
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact("10:00AM", "hh:mmtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime result = DateTime.Now + time.TimeOfDay;
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/0WPcAr)

**Edit**: If you want to add the `TimeSpan` to midnight use `DateTime.Today` instead of `DateTime.Now`.